# Declaring Private variable in a class

Tags: vba, class

I just found another way to declare a private variable in a class and wonder how does such complexity helps.

I declare a private variable as `Private m_IsCancelled As Boolean`. I access the simply `m_IsCancelled = True` within the class.

I noted others do this instead:

```
Private Type TView
    IsCancelled As Boolean
End Type
Private this As TView
```

and access the variable doing  `this.IsCancelled = True`

What are the advantages for such complexity? Yes, it save typing the word `Private` but need `this.` instead. Thanks!

Comment: I found [Classes in VBA](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/Classes.aspx) by Chip Pearson to explain what this is well. Also [Userform1.Show](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/) helps explain some benefits of writing your code this way.

Comment: See this: https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2018/04/25/private-this-as-tsomething/

Comment: Thank you for sharing the links. Got it!